# Pinging Computer through specefic route

Tags: graph, network-programming, ping

I have a network of computers connected in form of a graph.

I want to ping from one computer(A) to another computer(B). A and B are connected to each other through many different ways, but I want to PING via only a particular edges only. I have the information of the edges to be followed during pinging available at both A and B.

How should I do this?

Comment: It seems that you need strict source routing for that purpose. See IP protocol options for more detail.

Comment: @Vishal, I think that you have a better chance to get an answer to this on serverfault

Comment: I will try there too, any ways I think strict source routing will serve the purpose

Comment: @Shiraz not necessarily, this looks like it might be a programming question...need more information from the poster...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could source route the ping but the return would choose its own path.

Furthermore, source-routed packets are often filtered due to security concerns. (Not always, they are useful and sometimes even required at edge routers.)

If the machines are under your local administrative control, then you could ensure that source-routed packets are permitted. As long as you are able to start a daemon on machine ***B***, you could also easily enough design your own ping protocol that generates source-routed echo returns.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is actually done by routing protocols that are configured on the media in between the computers (routers I expect). I think there isn't a way where you can say "use that specific route". The routers have different protocols (OSPF, EIGRP, RIPv2) and they do the load balancing. The only way you would be sure of one specific route is to use static routing, but this isn't dynamically done where your computer decides the route.

This is normal because :

if you would be able to chose a route, DoS would be quite  easy to do to kill one route.